# TypeScript string interpolation not working in Angular project service file

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

Following is code for an Angular project service:

```
@Injectable()
export class FetchDataService {
  fetch(link){
    console.log('this is a ${link}');
  }
}
```

I'm calling this method in the component passing a string as an arguement.

Console Output:
the link is ${link}

Comment: If you use the 3 first words of your question on a google search, you will notice that your error is a typo: you arent using backticks. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html

Answer (score 7):

Try with backticks like so

```
@Injectable()
export class FetchDataService {
  fetch(link){
    console.log(`this is a ${link}`);
  }
}
```

It's called template literal and you can find more info here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! I was trying to reproduce a YT tutorial, and that backtick looked just like an apostrophe :(  (and I'm not new to backticks, only to Angular :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can to use following:

```
console.log('this is a' + link);
```